# Why does R sometimes crash and shut down when a Shiny App fails to terminate by x-ing out of the window?

Tags: r, shiny, restart

I usually close a Shiny App by x-ing out of the App's window as shown in the 1st image below. Depending on the App, sometimes this doesn't stop the App so I then go to the R studio console and click on "Stop" as shown in the 2nd image below. Sometimes this doesn't stop the App either, and R shuts down and restarts after a warning window pops up asking me if I want to restart R: clicking "No" doesn't stop the runaway App, so the only way I know how to stop the App is to click "Yes" and restart.

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

As far as I can tell the Apps where this happens are bug-free, in the sense they work fine for me and I got no other errors messages or warnings.

1st image, how I normally stop an App:

[image]

2nd image, where I go on R Studio console to stop a runaway App:

[image]

Comment: While the apps appear to be working fine for you, it could be a number of things that you aren't aware of and/or don't trigger in normal usage. This might be a bug in R, `shiny`, or the RStudio IDE itself. Can you make a small, reproducible example that can produce the incorrect behavior? If you start with a vanilla "hello world" shiny app and cannot reproduce, then start adding small components (one at a time) from your real app until you can reproduce the crash, then post that app. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, will try. After posting this last night, I tried crashing that App over and over and over, running the most ridiculous scenarios, and I couldn't get the App to crash again! Like hearing a knocking noise in your engine that seems to stop whenever you try showing it to your mechanic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the solution posted on Posit Community: [R crashes shiny app](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-crashes-when-closing-shiny-app-window-instead-of-clicking-red-stop-button-in-rstudio/131951)

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output, session) {  
session$onSessionEnded(function() { stopApp() })}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```